# how to access firestore from firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have started a Firebase project for a serverless web application. From the client-side I can access the Firestore database. From the serverless-side I have written a function to be called on http request. The function is trying to access the database by means of a Firestore object but it is failing because the Firestore object has no collection() function as I think it should have. In the output I show the content of the Firestore object.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.noteList = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  db = functions.firestore;
  console.dir(db);
  db.collection("notes").listDocuments().then(documentRefs => {
   return db.getAll(documentRefs);
  }).then(documentSnapshots => {
   res.json(documentSnapshots);
  });
});
```

output:

```
{ provider: 'google.firestore',
  service: 'firestore.googleapis.com',
  defaultDatabase: '(default)',
  document: [Function: document],
  namespace: [Function: namespace],
  database: [Function: database],
  _databaseWithOpts: [Function: _databaseWithOpts],
  _namespaceWithOpts: [Function: _namespaceWithOpts],
  _documentWithOpts: [Function: _documentWithOpts],
  DatabaseBuilder: [Function: DatabaseBuilder],
  NamespaceBuilder: [Function: NamespaceBuilder],
  snapshotConstructor: [Function: snapshotConstructor],
  beforeSnapshotConstructor: [Function: beforeSnapshotConstructor],
  DocumentBuilder: [Function: DocumentBuilder] }
Function crashed
TypeError: db.collection is not a function
```

For comparison this is how I access the database from the client-side, this is working:

```
function main() {
  var db = firebase.firestore();
  db.collection("global").doc("public").get().then(
    function(r) {
      var number_span = document.getElementById("number_span");
      data = r.data();
      number_span.textContent = "" + data.counter;
    });
}
```

Of course the firebase object is obtained in different ways. Maybe some configuration is missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use a Firestore SDK (typically via the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)) to access Firestore.  The Cloud Functions SDK (firebase-functions) does not do this for you.  All it does is help you specify the functions you want to deploy.  The body of the function should use the Firestore SDK.

```
// require and initialize the admin SDK
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// now use the SDK in the body of the function
admin.firestore().collection(...).doc(...)
```

The Admin SDK just wraps the [Cloud Firestore Node SDK](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.20.x/), so use its reference to navigate the APIs.